# Is it possible to put multiple relation constraints in a single method in Eloquent?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a query that looks like this:

```
Post::whereHas('comments', function ($query) {
    $query->where('content', 'like', 'foo%');
})->whereHas('comments', function ($query) {
    $query->where('content', 'like', 'bar%');
})->get()
```

Like a need all posts, which have one comment with text like 'foo' and also one comment with text like 'bar'. Can I somehow mix those two requests in a single one?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible to chain multiple where clauses but you can only use `::` once (after the model name), for all the others it should be `->` just like how you added the `->get()`.

So you would end up with:

```
Post::whereHas('comments', function ($query) {
    $query->where('content', 'like', 'foo%');
})->whereHas('comments', function ($query) {
    $query->where('content', 'like', 'bar%');
})->get()
```

Comment: I just mistyped it, i was using the arrow not double semicolon. What I wanted to ask, is there any way, not to use 'whereHas' twice?

Comment: Yes, the second `whereHas` should be named `orWhereHas`.